# После закрытия модульного окна звук видео не пропадает

Tags: javascript, видео, iframe

Похожие темы здесь есть, но не одно из решений мне не подошло.

После закрытия видео звук продолжает воспроизводиться. То есть видео продолжает воспроизведение где то там на фоне. Вот код, под кодом описание что пробовал, cms DLE.

HTML

```js
    $('body').on('click','.js-trailer',function(){
        $("#trailer-box").dialog({
            modal: false,
            show: 'fade',
            hide: 'fade',
            width: 800,
            close: function(event) {
               $(this).find("iframe").attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; })}
        }); 
        return false;
    });
```

```html
  <div class="video-box hidden trailer-box" id="trailer-box" title="{title} трейлер">
      <div class="dleplyrplayer" style="width:100%;max-width:auto;" theme="light">
          <video title="{title} сотреть в хорошем качестве" poster="[xfvalue_oblogka]" preload="none" controls>    
              <source type="video/mp4" src="[xfvalue_trailer]">
          </video>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Эту часть кода я сам прилепил

```js
close: function(event) {
$(this).find("iframe").attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; })}
```

Я прекрасно понимаю что этот кусок для iframe, и он прекрасно работает, если я HTML заменяю на iframe с Ютуба. Но при работе с `<video>` идет только запуск, при закрытии видео не останавливается. Пробовал менять ("iframe") на ("video") и ("source"). Результата не дало.

Comment: Пример https://jsfiddle.net/kmh7eazo/

Comment: Вы меня сильно переоценили. Я в двух строках блуждаю третий день. Я когда вижу столько кода, меня трясет. Я разве что могу заменить iframe на video. Но это не помогает, не подскажете что туда надо вставить?

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодится, человек мне с форума помог исправить

```js
$('body').on('click','.js-trailer',function(){
        $("#trailer-box").dialog({
            modal: false,
            show: 'fade',
            hide: 'fade',
            width: 800,
            close: function(event) {$('.dleplyrplayer video').trigger('pause'); }
        }); 
        return false;
    });
```

Обсуждалось здесь [здесь](https://dle-faq.ru/faq/common/25557-kak-ostanovit-video-v-standartnom-modalnom-okne-pri-ego-zakrytii.html)